# Get top level parent node for any node

Tags: algorithm, scala, data-structures, tree

Given the format at the end of the question, what's the best way to get the top-level name for a given item?
Top-level names are the ones with parentId = 1.

```scala
def getTopLevel(name: String): String = {
    // Environment(150) -> Environment(150) - since its parentId is 1
    // Assassination -> Security - since Assassination(12) -> Terrorism(10) -> Security(2)
}
```

Here's my current approach but is there something better?

unmapped = categories.size

Loop through this list until there are still unmapped items.
- build a Map(Int, String) for top levels.
- build a Map(Int, Int) - that maps an id to top level id.
- keep track of unmapped items

once loop exits, I can use both Maps to get the job done.

```
[
    {
        "name": "Destination Overview",
        "id": 1,
        "parentId": null
    },
    {
        "name": "Environment",
        "id": 150,
        "parentId": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "Security",
        "id": 2,
        "parentId": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "Armed Conflict",
        "id": 10223,
        "parentId": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "Civil Unrest",
        "id": 21,
        "parentId": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "Terrorism",
        "id": 10,
        "parentId": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "Assassination",
        "id": 12,
        "parentId": 10
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually two questions.

1. Parsing Json into a Scala collection and
2. Using that collection to trace items back to the top parent

For the first question, you can use [play-json](https://github.com/playframework/play-json). The second part can be handled with a tail-recursive function. Here is the full program that solves both problems:

```
import play.api.libs.json.{Json, Reads}

case class Node(name: String, id: Int, parentId: Option[Int])
object JsonParentFinder {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val s =
      """
        |[
        |    {
        |        "name": "Destination Overview",
        |        "id": 1,
        |        "parentId": null
        |    },
        |    {
        |        "name": "Environment",
        |        "id": 150,
        |        "parentId": 1
        |    },
        // rest of the json
        |]
        |""".stripMargin

    implicit val NodeReads : Reads[Node] =Json.reads[Node]
    val r = Json.parse(s).as[Seq[Node]]
      .map(x => x.id -> x).toMap

    println(getTopLevelNode(150, r))
    println(getTopLevelNode(12, r))
  }

  def getTopLevelNode(itemId : Int, nodes: Map[Int, Node], path : List[Node] = List.empty[Node]) : List[Node] = {
    if(nodes(itemId).id == 1)
      nodes(itemId) +: path  
    else
      getTopLevelNode(nodes(nodes(itemId).parentId.get).id, nodes, nodes(itemId) +: path)
  }
}
```

Output will be:

```
List(Node(Destination Overview,1,None), Node(Environment,150,Some(1)))
List(Node(Destination Overview,1,None), Node(Security,2,Some(1)), Node(Terrorism,10,Some(2)), Node(Assassination,12,Some(10)))
```

A few notes:

- I have not implemented comprehensive error-handling logic. The implicit assumption is that the only item with `parentId==None` is the root node. `nodes(itemId).parentId.get` could lead to failure.
- Also, in creating the map, the assumption is that all items have unique ids.
- Another assumption is that all nodes eventually have a path to the root node. If that is not the case, this will fail. But it should be straightforward to fix these cases by adding more stop conditions.
- I am prepending items to the accumulator list(named `path` here) because prepend operation on Scala's lists takes constant time. You can just `reverse` the resulting list or use another data structure like `Vector` to efficiently build the path.